# cannot access Frame, file does not contain class frame

Tags: java, awt

```
import java.awt.*;   

class FirstFrame extends Frame {

    FirstFrame() {
        Button b = new Button("ok");
        b.setBounds(30, 100, 80, 30);
        add(b);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        FirstFrame f = new FirstFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: The class is called `FirstFrame`

Comment: yes i have called FirstFrame extends Frame class

Comment: Then what is the question...?

Comment: but error show "cannot access Frame, file does not cantain class Frame "

Comment: Nope, works fine for me.  Is the file name called `FirstFrame.java`?

Comment: but i have get error....why

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: What error? When? How?

Comment: cannot access Frame,file does not contain class frame

Comment: Whatever resource being used for learning?  Burn it.  AWT (yuck(1)) `setBounds(..)` (groan) `setSize(..)` (yawn) `setLayout(null)` (retch..). 1) Why AWT rather than Swing?  See this answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.  If you need to support older AWT based APIs, see [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html).

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207750405/comments/207415345

Answer (score 0):

You may have accidentally created any other .java file named "Frame" in your present directory.
If you have any such .java file then rename it to other name

Answer (score 0):

It's simply means that you have created a file with name  "Frame.java", just change it's name and your run your program.
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
As your program cannot access the actual Java.awt.Frame class, as you have created some other Frame class, so your program is unable to differentiate because of ambiguous statement.
Stay Blessed!

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but if anyone else needs it, the solution that worked for me was to click on:

[image: here is the solution]

Found it on the intelij community, all credits go to that guy